# Using VLOOKUP to search & display information

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have two Sheets

1. Search (This is where the search takes place & then will return the results of the search)

[image]

2. Records(Where the information is stored - This is a hidden sheet)

[image]

First Issue: I can't get it to find the Data in `Records`

```
=VLOOKUP(G18,'Records'!,A21,0)
```

What I'm aiming to do is.

1. User searches for username in 'Search'- Using a search Cell
2. Information matching the users search (Stored in Records)is returned and displayed in 'Search'

Comment: `username` is unique or 1 user name may exists multiple times in `Records` sheet?

Comment: Username may exist multiple times. So I want it to pull all records of that 'username' and display it in the search sheet

Comment: Can you not simply use a filter?

Answer (score 0):

'Records'!,A21 - this means you are just searching in that cell [A21] from records sheet.

Comment: So to have it select Colums A-F would I need to do 'Records'!$A$F.

So the formular should look like 
=VLOOKUP(G18,'Records'!,A:F,0)